# Cant identify WiFi Direct peer when device is connected to a WiFi Interface

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, android-4.2-jelly-bean, wifi-direct

I am working on WiFi Direct in android Jelly bean 4.1 with samsung(google) nexus device. I am able to discover the peer and connect with it when I am purely on wifi direct and when the devices are not connected to any other external interfaces.

But as a test I connected both devices to my Router, then started wifi direct on one device and created a group. After that I started next device and when I call discover peers its a success.

Immedialtely I call requestPeers and its returning an empty list of peers. But the same is working when both devices are not connected to any other interface.

How can I do this properly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to connect to a router in addition to your two devices?

My devices require that I disable regular WiFi when using WiFiDirect which leads me to believe they cannot be used at the same time.